# Trigger on SQLite not working

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have built 2 tables (t_top and t_rest) on a db and the first should contain up to 5 numbers, while the second should contain more. We can only insert number to the t_top using an active trigger that saves 5 numbers to t_top and then if a sixth is inserted, then if it's greater than one in t_top, the sixth is inserted in t_top while the smallest from the 5 existing in it moves to t_rest.

F.e. if we have t_top=[1,3,5,7,9} and t_rest is empty, then if we insert 8 we finally have t_top=[3,5,7,8,9] and t_rest=[1]. That trigger works for me.

However, i've written another trigger, which should move numbers in case of deletion from t_top. If f.e. we delete 5, we should have 1 moved back to t_top.

My trigger is the following, but not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tracks_less_than_5
AFTER DELETE on t_top
WHEN
5>(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_top)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO t_top
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM t_min
WHERE id = max_id;
DELETE FROM t_min
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM t_min
WHERE id = max_id;
END
```

I guess something is not right, but cannot figure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM t_min
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM t_min
WHERE id = max_id;
```

-this does not have sense because the syntax of DELETE is `DELETE FROM table WHERE ...` I guess you wanted something like this:

```
DELETE FROM t_min WHERE id=(
SELECT MAX(id) FROM t_min
);
```

Comment: This looks better, but i get a "misuse of aggregate: max()". No idea why

Comment: Try this edit (be careful, do it if you know what to do)